# Numpy: How to elementwise-multiply two vectors, shape (n,1) and (n,)?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Elementwise multiplication of two vectors is no problem if they both have the same shape, say both (n,1) or both (n,). If one vector has shape (n,1) and the other (n,), though, the `*`-operator returns something funny.

```
a = np.ones((3,1))
b = np.ones((3,))
print a * b
```

The resulting nxn-matrix contains A_{i,j}=a_i*b_j.

How can I do elementwise multiplication for the `a` and `b` then?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Slice the vectors in a way that makes their shape match:

```
a[:, 0] * b
```

or

```
a * b[:, None]
```

Comment: `a.reshape(-1) * b` or `a * b.reshape((-1, 1))` is another way to do basically the same thing. (`-1` means "as many as make it fit with this shape.")

Answer (score 4):

Add a second axis to `b` to that `a` and `b` have the same dimensions:

```
>>> a * b[:,np.newaxis]
array([[ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.]])
```

Alternatively, transpose `a` so that broadcasting works:

```
>>> a.T * b
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

(You'd probably want to transpose the result.)

Comment: I think the `.T` solution is the nicest one.  It requires the least typing and the least thinking.