# how to multiply 2 numpy array with different dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I try to multiply 2 matrix x,y with shape (41) and (41,6)
as it is supposed to broadcast the single matrix to every arrow in the multi-dimensions

I want to do it as :

```
x*y
```

but i get this error

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (41,6) (41,)
```

Is there anything I miss here to make that possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly sure, what you are trying to achieve. Maybe you could give an example of your input and your expected output. One possibility is:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]])
y = np.array([1, 2, 3])
res = x * np.transpose(np.array([y,]*2))
```

This will multiply each column of x with y, so the result of the above example is:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 4],
       [3, 6]])
```

Comment: Yes, Using transpose in turn around the columns to arrows . That helps. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Broadcasting involves 2 steps

- give all arrays the same number of dimensions
- expand the `1` dimensions to match the other arrays

With your inputs

```
(41,6) (41,)
```

one  is 2d, the other 1d;  broadcasting can change the 1d to `(1, 41)`, but it does not automatically expand in the other direction `(41,1)`.

```
(41,6) (1,41)
```

Neither (41,41) or (6,41) matches the other.

So you need to change your `y` to `(41,1)` or the `x` to `(6,41)`

```
x.T*y
x*y[:,None]
```

I'm assuming, of course, that you want element by element multiplication, not the `np.dot` matrix product.

Answer (score 3):

You can try out this, it will works!

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]])
>>> y = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> np.dot(y,x)
array([ 6, 12])
```

Answer (score 2):

The multiplication of a ND array (say A) with a 1D one (B) is performed on the last axis by default, which means that the multiplication A * B is only valid if

`A.shape[-1] == len(B)`

A manipulation on A and B is needed to multiply A with B on another axis than -1:

## Method 1: swapaxes

Swap the axes of A so that the axis to multiply with B appear on last postion

`C = (A.swapaxes(axis, -1) * B).swapaxes(axis, -1)`

example

```
A = np.arange(2 * 3 * 4).reshape((2, 3, 4))
B = np.array([0., 1., 2.])
print(A)
print(B)
```

pormpts :

```
(A)
[[[ 0  1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6  7]
  [ 8  9 10 11]]

 [[12 13 14 15]
  [16 17 18 19]
  [20 21 22 23]]]
(B) 
[0. 1. 2.]
```

A * B returns :

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3,4) (3,)
```

now multiply A with B on axis 1

```
 axis = 1
 C = (A.swapaxes(axis, -1) * B).swapaxes(axis, -1)
```

returns C :

```
    array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
            [ 4.,  5.,  6.,  7.],
            [16., 18., 20., 22.]],
    
           [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
            [16., 17., 18., 19.],
            [40., 42., 44., 46.]]])
```

Note that first raws of A have been multiplied by 0
last raws have been multiplied by 2

## Method 2: reshape B

make B have the same number of dimensions than A, place the items of B on the dimension to be multiplied with A

```
A * B.reshape((1, len(B), 1))
```

or equivalently using the convenient 'numpy.newaxis' syntax :

```
A * B[np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis]
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you're expecting. One simple solution would be:

`y*x`

That should give you a matrix of dimensions (1,6).

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to multiply  X of dimension (n) to Y of dimension(n,m), you may consider the answers from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948042/numpy-how-to-elementwise-multiply-two-vectors-shape-n-1-and-n)

Tips can be found in the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)#In_programming_languages) as well:

> In Python with the numpy numerical library or the sympy symbolic library, multiplication of array objects as a1*a2 produces the Hadamard product, but with otherwise matrix objects m1*m2 will produce a matrix product.

Simply speaking, slice it up to arrays and perform x*y, or use other routes to fit the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

So, if `x` has shape (41,6) and `y` (41,), I'd use `np.expand_dims()` to add an empty, second dimension (index 1) to `y`, i.e.,

```
x * np.expand_dims(y, 1)
```

This will automatically yield a result with shape (41,6).